# How do I negate a regular expression in MariaDB SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

I looked over the docs at

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regular-expressions-overview/
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/not-regexp/

I tried

```
... address_one not rlike '\d';
15707 rows in set (0.52 sec)

... address_one not regexp '\d';
15707 rows in set (0.56 sec)

... address_one !regexp '\d';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

... not(address_one regexp '\d');
15707 rows in set (0.55 sec)
```

I want to find all rows where there are *no* digits. `^\d` will not work because that will match a digit at the beginning of the line only and `[^\d]` will match any letter like 'a'. It doesn't seem to be negating the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I fixed it with `address_one not regexp '\\d'`, using a double backslash. `\d` isn't even found on the [documentation page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regular-expressions-overview/).

Comment: You were on wrong page. See *Generic Character Types* on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/

Comment: You can always use:  `address_one not regexp '[0-9]'`.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10.0 and Mysql 8.0 have `\d` (and similar animals).

All(?) have `[0-9]` and `[[:digit:]]`.

To negate the entire expression:

```
x NOT RLIKE   '[0-9]'
x NOT REGEXP  '[0-9]'
NOT (x RLIKE  '[0-9]')
NOT (x REGEXP '[0-9]')
```

Negating the regexp with `^` is not straightforward.  To find rows with no digits is equivalent to finding rows with only non-digits:

```
x RLIKE '^[^0-9]*$'
```